# Why include IDs of parent resources in REST endpoint?

Tags: rest, uri

Say I have a company directory application, so `Companies` have `Employees`. It's pretty clear to me why you would have the following `GET` endpoints:

```
api/companies                # Get all company records
api/companies/{id}           # Get company with specified id
api/companies/{id}/employees # Get all employees for the company with specified id
```

But say I want to get a specific employee record. It seems the common pattern is to provide a resource:

```
api/companies/{id}/employees/{id}
```

But assuming an `employee` record is only owned by one `company`, why would you provide the `company`'s id in that URI? Isn't that simply a redundant parameter? Even if you need to acquire the `company` for some kind of logic behind the scenes, you can do that easily enough by just checking the parent of the `employee`. So my gut says to make the endpoint like this:

```
api/companies/employees/{id}
```

Yet the former pattern is so pervasive, I feel like I'm missing something. Would someone care to explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee that employee IDs are unique across companies.

In other words, we may run into this scenario:

```
> GET api/companies/4711/employees/42
Smith, Winston

> GET api/companies/815/employees/42
O'Brien, Seamus
```

If we really had the case where employee IDs are a resource independent of companies (such as the [SSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number) in the U.S.), then `api/employees/{id}` would be much better.

Comment: GUIDs would fix that problem.  SSN's [are not guaranteed to be unique](http://www.aol.com/article/2010/08/12/your-social-security-number-may-not-be-unique-to-you/19590884/).

Comment: Ah, ok. I assumed they were. Good to know.

Comment: Which is why I always use synthetic primary keys.  I've seen too many cases where a natural key was assumed to be unique when it actually wasn't.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with supporting `GET /companies/{id}/employees/{id}` and `GET /companies/employees/{id}` is that the meaning of the path segment after `/companies` is overloaded. It would represent either "a specific company" or "a property shared by all companies". It's annoying to implement on your side, confusing for clients, and now you have to track that you've removed "employees" as a possible company id.

If there are no properties of an employee that differ among companies, then just do:

```
GET /companies/{id}
GET /employees/{id}
```

You can also support either `GET /employees?company={id}`, `GET /companies/{id}/employees`, or both, but any `self` links for the employees should point back to their canonical location (`/employees/{id}`).

Your ids for employees and companies should almost certainly be generated by your system and not related to user-specific data, because that can change.